# MariaDB DATETIME Index not working with Between FROM_UNIXTIME()

Tags: datetime, indexing, mariadb

I have a table with DATETIME field, which is indexed by a BTree. Now i want to query it with following statement:

```
SELECT
  count(us.CITY) as metric,
  us.CITY as Name,
  us.LATITUDE as latitude,
  us.LONGITUDE as longitude
FROM
  FACT
LEFT JOIN
  USER us
ON
  us.ID_USER = FACT.USER
WHERE
  ASSESSMENT_DATE BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1601568552) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1604028277)
GROUP BY us.CITY, us.LATITUDE, us.LONGITUDE;
```

EXPLAIN:

```
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys              | key     | key_len | ref                          | rows   | Extra                                        |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | FACT  | ALL    | INDEX_FACT_ASSESSMENT_DATE | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                         | 762621 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | us    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                    | PRIMARY | 46      | dwh0.FACT.USER,dwh0.FACT.ENV |      1 |                                              |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Interestingly, by only changing the dates manually into the DATETIME Format string it uses the index. But the FROM_UNIXTIME() function should in my opinion return the exactly same thing...

```
SELECT
  count(us.CITY) as metric,
  us.CITY as Name,
  us.LATITUDE as latitude,
  us.LONGITUDE as longitude
FROM
FACT
LEFT JOIN
   USER us
ON
  us.ENV = FACT.ENV AND us.ID_USER = FACT.USER
WHERE
-- ASSESSMENT_DATE BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1596649101) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1599108827)
  ASSESSMENT_DATE BETWEEN '2020-08-05 11:30:11.987' AND '2020-09-03 11:30:11.987'
GROUP BY us.CITY, us.LATITUDE, us.LONGITUDE;
```

EXPLAIN:

```
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys              | key                        | key_len | ref                          | rows   | Extra
     |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | FACT  | range  | INDEX_FACT_ASSESSMENT_DATE | INDEX_FACT_ASSESSMENT_DATE | 5       | NULL                         | 132008 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | us    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                    | PRIMARY                    | 46      | dwh0.FACT.USER,dwh0.FACT.ENV |      1 |
     |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+------------------------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Can anyone refer to such a problem? the where clause is generated by grafana, so i can not change that, but the rest i can change if it changes something.

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: Which version are you actually running in production or are planning to run?  I'm surprised that the first query is not using the index, but if the second version works, then what is the problem?

Comment: MySQL probably considers that doing a full table scan will be more performant than applying the FROM_UNIXTIME conversion to the whole index tree. You can try to force the index usage with a hint to see if you have an improvement: `FROM  FACT USE INDEX(INDEX_FACT_ASSESSMENT_DATE)`

Comment: Version is 10.3.29

the problem is, that the date selection is made by another applications macros (grafana) which uses UNIXTIME for everything. So i can not change that...

Comment: @ThomasG Thanks for the hint, tried it, MariaDB still means not using the index is more performant -.-

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bothering.. after around 10^5 more inserts, it works for both cases... Maybe it was just bad luck